# Cygwin's Emacs crashes on "//"

Tags: emacs, cygwin, 64-bit

**What I'm using**

I am using Cygwin 64-Bit. In the shell, If I type:

> uname -srv

I get:

> CYGWIN_NT-6.1 1.7.34(0.285/5/3) 2015-02-04 12:14

If I right-click on cygwin1.dll, "Properties" under "File version" I get:

> 1007.34.0.0

In the shell, if I type

> emacs --version

I get:

> GNU Emacs 24.4.1

**The problem**

If I run emacs and create a c-file, such as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

That works fine.

If I then want to do something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
//add a comment here
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

...as soon as I enter the slashes, Emacs crashes. On entering the first slash, it provides auto-complete options, if I choose one, things are still good. However if I don't, as soon as I just enter the 2nd slash Emacs crashes.

Is this a known bug?

P.S.: I know I can install Emacs outside Cygwin and even get an Emacs version that somehow includes Cygwin. But I'd rather stay with what I have. So please don't suggest this as a workaround. I'm already aware of it.

Comment: I have now changed to cygwin_x86 (win32), and the problem is gone, or rather not there in the 32-bit version.

Comment: try turning off font lock mode... M-x font-lock-mode toggles it on/off, before adding the //.